# Aggregate averages from Embedded Documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

My document structure is shown here:

```python
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52517d9e6e0af435ddd48219"),
    "date" : ISODate("2013-10-06T18:11:26.329Z"),
    "engines" : {
        "ahnlab" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "ahnlab",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 1,
            "task_id" : "7fac4f67-2bde-49de-980a-4f7fa1d46db7",
            "threat" : "EICAR_Test_File"
        },
        "avast" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "avast",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "fdce50e9-9bf3-4cc9-91a4-b674a108d478",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "avg" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "avg",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 1,
            "task_id" : "4bdb4a37-80ab-4631-8587-edcbde7e2592",
            "threat" : "EICAR_Test"
        },
        "avira" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "avira",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "43b43bab-ff67-440c-9919-f6241ccaf539",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "bitdefender" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "bitdefender",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "ba7efe74-ef93-465f-b6c3-6c4fc746934d",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "comodo" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "comodo",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "831d2dc8-704b-4eb7-9a75-9a0364a8ab09",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "drweb" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "drweb",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "ebb758c3-9146-4a99-b36f-0fb6ee024a33",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "f-prot" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "f-prot",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "13590a25-ac0d-4b1b-b93e-bc715009432a",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "forticlient" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "forticlient",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "kaspersky" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "kaspersky",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "malwarebytes" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "malwarebytes",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "a97f3d9a-d6a9-44df-8355-c053e9f4980a",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "mcafee" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "mcafee",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 1,
            "task_id" : "e7a592bb-84fc-4c47-a1ed-3719874b19cc",
            "threat" : "EICAR test file"
        },
        "msessentials" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "msessentials",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "01c9fb71-155a-473d-b45c-91fa117ae649",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "nod32" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "nod32",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "a715cc8f-0e2f-4698-b883-a35fa6add13e",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "norman" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "norman",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "29da2955-0674-45d2-ac4d-c0b3ea401cba",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "norton" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "norton",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "c4cd1e3e-2f0d-4bf6-84cf-ab0962f7f4ed",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        "panda" : {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "panda",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "b0888f7c-e4a4-4b4e-b163-21d283e166f1",
            "threat" : ""
        }
    },
    "expiration_date" : ISODate("2013-10-06T18:11:36.329Z"),
    "file_name" : "ffgtr.exe",
    "scan_status" : "DONE",
    "task_id" : "4ce4ae9e-ef0a-476a-8189-92a5bfe328bd"
}
```

I would like to project with aggregation the fields 'date' and 'definitions' of every engine. 
('definitions' is an embedded field)

I succeeded doing it only if I specify the specific engine:

```python
cursor = collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "date": { "$gte": startdate } } },
    {'$project': { "def": "$engines.avast.definitions","date":1,"_id": 0 }}
], allowDiskUse=True)
```

But I would like to run the query for all engines without specifying specific engine, something like:

```python
cursor = collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "date": { "$gte": startdate } } },
    {'$project': { "def": "$engines.$elemMatch.definitions","date":1,"_id": 0 }}
], allowDiskUse=True)
```

(which doesn't work)

What I want to find is the average difference between "date" and each "engine" definition date per engine type.

Comment: It won't work like that. You should have defined engines as an "array/list"  where there was a "consistent" path to each "definitions" value. The aggregation framework, just like other MongoDB query operators cannot traverse object structures like this. The only way with the present structure is to use mapReduce. But then you don't actually state what you are trying to do beyond that step.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is the structure of your data. In order to work with the aggregation framework and also happily work with most other MongoDB query operations and indexing practices then your data should be structured like this instead.

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52517d9e6e0af435ddd48219"),
    "date" : ISODate("2013-10-06T18:11:26.329Z"),
    "engines" : [
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "ahnlab",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 1,
            "task_id" : "7fac4f67-2bde-49de-980a-4f7fa1d46db7",
            "threat" : "EICAR_Test_File"
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "avast",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "fdce50e9-9bf3-4cc9-91a4-b674a108d478",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "avg",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 1,
            "task_id" : "4bdb4a37-80ab-4631-8587-edcbde7e2592",
            "threat" : "EICAR_Test"
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "avira",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "43b43bab-ff67-440c-9919-f6241ccaf539",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "bitdefender",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "ba7efe74-ef93-465f-b6c3-6c4fc746934d",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "comodo",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "831d2dc8-704b-4eb7-9a75-9a0364a8ab09",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "drweb",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "ebb758c3-9146-4a99-b36f-0fb6ee024a33",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "f-prot",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "13590a25-ac0d-4b1b-b93e-bc715009432a",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "forticlient",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "kaspersky",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "malwarebytes",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "a97f3d9a-d6a9-44df-8355-c053e9f4980a",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "mcafee",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 1,
            "task_id" : "e7a592bb-84fc-4c47-a1ed-3719874b19cc",
            "threat" : "EICAR test file"
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "msessentials",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "01c9fb71-155a-473d-b45c-91fa117ae649",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "nod32",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "a715cc8f-0e2f-4698-b883-a35fa6add13e",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "norman",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "29da2955-0674-45d2-ac4d-c0b3ea401cba",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "norton",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "c4cd1e3e-2f0d-4bf6-84cf-ab0962f7f4ed",
            "threat" : ""
        },
        {
            "definitions" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "panda",
            "node_name" : "",
            "status" : 4,
            "task_id" : "b0888f7c-e4a4-4b4e-b163-21d283e166f1",
            "threat" : ""
        }
    ],
    "expiration_date" : ISODate("2013-10-06T18:11:36.329Z"),
    "file_name" : "ffgtr.exe",
    "scan_status" : "DONE",
    "task_id" : "4ce4ae9e-ef0a-476a-8189-92a5bfe328bd"
}
```

Then working with that structure is as simple as processing [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and then a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) for your results:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$engines" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$engines.name",
        "avgInterval": { "$avg": {
            "$subtract": [ "$date", "$engines.definitions" ]
        }}
    }}
])
```

The difference will be in milliseconds between two date objects.

Otherwise you are stuck with traversing the object keys in code using JavaScript with mapReduce:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var doc = this;
        Object.keys(doc.engines).forEach(function(key) {
            emit( key, 
                ( doc.date.valueOf() - 
                    doc.engines[key].definitions.valueOf())
            );
        })
   },
   function(key,values) { 
       return ( Array.sum(values) / values.length );
   },
   { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
);
```

Both will give you the average value for each engine "name" accross the collection or other query input.

Try to change the structure as it is better suited to your ongoing needs and provides much faster processing.